# Main Menu Not Appearing On My Android Phone

Tags: java, android, menu

I'm trying to set up a main menu but it's not appearing on my phone. The main menu xml is already set up and everything compiles, but when I try it on my phone, it doesn't appear. And the build target is Android 4.0.3, the same as my phone. Below is the java code, I hope someone can help me with this.

```
    package image.change;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;

    public class UserInterface extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

        }//end onCreate

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
            return true;

        }//end onCreateOptionsMenu

    }//end UserInterface
```

Comment: When you pressed your phone's MENU button, what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this...

**Inflating the Menu:**

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.menu_bookmark:
            // Single menu item is selected do something
            // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Bookmark is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_save:
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Save is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_search:
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Search is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_share:
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Share is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_delete:
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Delete is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_preferences:
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Preferences is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This To Build Your `MENU`

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        boolean result=super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0,menu_1,1,"Register");
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){       
            case menu_1:
                fnRegistration();
                return true;
        }         
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```